# inclined border and resizable

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new with CSS
I want to create resizable element like this in the picture.
I want to show a similar border. Please note that  it is inclined and double in the bottom corner.
How can I acheave this? 
In a next step I want to be able to resize it using the mouse
 
thank you
  [image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `resize: both;`

```css
div {
    border: 1px dashed #888;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: div {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

Comment: I think ,
this solution is not working with neither  internet explorer nor edge !!

Comment: Yes! it does not supports in both, [check here](http://caniuse.com/#search=resize), you can use jquery plugin either.